# android application in background background mode slows down the device

Tags: android, multithreading

My application plays audio track and goes into background. So far background audio playback(using AudioTrack) was working fine. I have implemented this using service. But after android os upgrade (1. 2.2 to 2.3 and 2.2 to 2.3) problem stared now background audio playback stutters or stucks when user traverse to other applications like gallary and emails.

Application goes background by pressing back button on main Activity. Though it also stutters when going into background using Home key.

Is this due to upgrade ?
How can i check priorities of application or threads of my application?

Any clue or someone has faced such awkward problem ?

```
m_thread1  = new Thread(
                new Runnable() 
                {
                    //! \brief Thread that updates time display and related fields
                    public void run() 
                    {                       
                        int tid,pri;
                        tid = Process.myTid();
                        Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_MORE_FAVORABLE);
                        pri = Process.getThreadPriority(tid);


                        while (!Thread.interrupted())
                        {
                            try 
                            {
                                JNI_performAudioPlayback();                             

                                Thread.sleep(10);
                                break;
                            }
                            catch (InterruptedException e) 
                            {
                                break;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                },"threadname"
        );
```

> Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_AUDIO Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND +
>   Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_MORE_FAVORABLE
>   Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND +
>   Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_FOREGROUND Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND

Total 7 threads are there which uses above mentioned priorities during their life cycle in service.

Thanks,
JRC

Answer (score 1):

This code was just what I was looking for but I had to slightly modify it to make it work for me.  Thus:

```
    private void outputTop(){
    int count = 0;
    int bufferSize = 8*1024;
    byte [] data;
    Process process = null;
    String out = "";        

    data = new byte[bufferSize];

    try { process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top -t -n 1"); } 
    catch (IOException e) {}

    if(process != null)
    {
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(process.getInputStream(), bufferSize);
        try 
        { 
            while ((count = bis.read(data, 0, bufferSize)) != -1) 
            {
                out += org.apache.http.util.EncodingUtils.getAsciiString(data, 0, count);                   
            }
        }

        catch(IOException e){ }

        if (bis != null)
        {               
            try { bis.close();} 
            catch (IOException e) {}

            writeToLogFile(out);                
        }
    }                   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try detecting what thread is consuming most CPU resources. Knowing that you can make further assumptions what is really going on.

Here's code sample to see the output of [top](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_%28software%29) command for threads.

```
int count = 0;
int bufferSize = 8*1024;
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top -t -n 1");
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(process.getInputStream(), bufferSize);
try { 
    while ((count = bis.read(data, 0, bufferSize)) != -1) {
         //output text data
    }
} finally {
    if (bis != null)
        bis.close();
}
```